# VBA VLookup Variable Troubles

Tags: vba, excel

Good afternoon,

I'm trying to write a worksheet_change macro that will use VLookup to populate an items description and construction time by simply imputting the items number.  There are two seperate sheets.  The first sheet is where I am inputting the item number and the second sheet is what holds that item numbers pertinent information that I want to transfer over.

The code I have right now for the vlookup is below:

```
description = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(103770, _
            sheet.Range(sheet.Cells(2, 1), sheet.Cells(2000, 9)), 2, False)
```

The procedure works fine when I manually input the "103770" item number but when I change that to a variable I get an error.  This is the code with the variable inserted:

```
description = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ERP, _
             sheet.Range(sheet.Cells(2, 1), sheet.Cells(2000, 9)), 2, False)
```

I have the variable ERP dimmed as a string.  While stepping through the program and taking note of the Locals window, the ERP is defined as "103770".  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: ... Looks like it should work.... What is the error you're getting?

Comment: I got it to work by changing the ERP dim to Long instead of String.

Comment: As you've seen, it was passing the variable in as a string when what you needed was a number.

Comment: And not that it's a huge deal, but if you want to you and it doesn't affect anything else, you can enter the Range in a shorter form: i.e. `.Range("A2:I200")`

Comment: What did you defined `description` as? Better yet, Name the Range `sheet.Range(sheet.Cells(2, 1), sheet.Cells(2000, 9))`, so `description = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ERP, ThisWorkbook.Names("TEST").RefersToRange, 2, False)`

Comment: Patrick and EndlessLoop.  I was going to get the Range named differently in the program as well.  I was just going through my code systematically so I could figure out where the proglem was.  Thanks for the input guys! Really appreciate it!